# Is there an alternative to LINQ let operator that doesn't hit performance?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ to Entity query which uses a select to transform raw data from the db into an object, performing some calculations in the process. The calculations are repeated a couple of times so I tried refactoring the LINQ to make use of a let. However, in doing so, performance is hit drastically. Is there an alternative to LET which I can use just for code re-usability without affecting performance?

```
var defaultHours = 40;
var defaultOldPersonPoints = 100;
var defaultYoungPersonPoints = 50;

// Example with no let but lots of ugly, unreadable, redundant code
var exampleNoLet =
    (from p in people
     join op in otherPeople
         on p.PersonId equals op.PersonId into inner
     from outer in inner.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
     select new
     {
         AllocatedPoints = (p.PersonTypeId == (int)PersonType.Old
                            ? defaultOldPersonPoints
                            : p.PersonTypeId == (int)PersonType.Young
                            ? defaultYoungPersonPoints : 0)
                            + (int)(
                            (p.PersonTypeId == (int)PersonType.Old
                            ? defaultOldPersonPoints
                            : p.PersonTypeId == (int)PersonType.Young
                            ? defaultYoungPersonPoints : 0)
                            * (p.ContractedHours.HasValue
                            ? (p.ContractedHours.Value - defaultHours) / defaultHours : 0))
     });


// Using the LET allows me to clean up the code somewhat but causes a massive performance hit
var exampleUsingLet =
    (from p in people
     join op in otherPeople
         on p.PersonId equals op.PersonId into inner
     from outer in inner.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
     let defaultPoints = p.PersonTypeId == (int)PersonType.Old
                            ? defaultOldPersonPoints
                            : p.PersonTypeId == (int)PersonType.Young
                            ? defaultYoungPersonPoints : 0
     let contractedHourRatio = p.ContractedHours.HasValue 
                            ? (p.ContractedHours.Value - defaultHours) / defaultHours : 0
     select new
     {
         AllocatedPoints = defaultPoints + (int)(defaultPoints * contractedHourRatio)
     });
```

Comment: Have you actually looked at the generated SQL?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead while it all comes down to the generated SQL, I'm interested here in readability without affecting generated SQL

Comment: Yes but why is it hurting performance? What is `let` doing exactly? Knowing that may give you some answers on how to refactor it in a way that it does the same thing.. without `let` (if indeed `let` is the cause..).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it assumed the issue was related to code where in fact it was environmental and is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3):

If the *query performance* is the problem, then consider moving that to LINQ-to-Objects. For example, at the moment, you aren't using anything other than `p` in the projection (it is not clear to me why you are doing what *appears to be* a left-outer-join, in fact), so you could just do something like:

```
var queryBase = from p in people
                join op in otherPeople
                on p.PersonId equals op.PersonId into inner
                from outer in inner.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
                select p;

var query = from p in queryBase.AsEnumerable() // <=== switch to LINQ-to-Objects
            let defaultPoints = p.PersonTypeId == (int)PersonType.Old
                        ? defaultOldPersonPoints
                        : p.PersonTypeId == (int)PersonType.Young
                        ? defaultYoungPersonPoints : 0
            let contractedHourRatio = p.ContractedHours.HasValue 
                        ? (p.ContractedHours.Value - defaultHours) / defaultHours : 0
            select new
            {
                AllocatedPoints = defaultPoints + (int)(defaultPoints * contractedHourRatio)
            });
```

Here, the SQL query should be pretty simple; all the more complex work is done in LINQ-to-Objects.

Comment: Looking back at the issue, the let version now performs faster than the alternate... so my issue no longer exists. It could have been the sql server instance performance at the time.

Comment: As such, I tried deleting the question but it wont let me due to your answer.